# Installing compizconfig settings manager causes "hide all normal windows and set focus to the desktop" to stop working

Tags: desktop, ubuntu-10.10, compiz

I've installed a CompizConfig Settings Manager on  Ubuntu 10.10. A filter in the program disables "hide all normal windows and set focus to the desktop" because of a conflict. I don't know what is causing the conflict - I tried changing its shortcut key but that didn't help. I also tried uninstalling CompizConfig Settings Manager, but still  it didn't help. I was thinking that there might be a configuration that have disabled it but I don't know where to look for it. How can I re-enable the shortcut to hide all windows and set focus to the desktop?

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same issue with Compiz. My system is Linux Mint tho.

When I enabled Compiz, the normal system keybindings, **for window manager only**, had perished.

The thing is, Compiz have its own keybindings. My Compiz settings have a "General Options" menu button.

[image]

Next, on the "Key bindings" tab

[image]

There is a binding called "Show Desktop". This is what you want. Be sure to have Compiz settings installed. My system have the package `compizconfig-settings-manager` for that.
Good luck with the accelerated desktop experience.